# Windows application freezes most of the time on button click

Tags: forms, winforms

I am working on a windows application which freezes most of the time on button click events on Home Page. Please find the code below for your reference. Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FileMigrationAgen
{
    public partial class HomePage : Form
    {
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tableLayoutPanel4_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SharepointMigration sharepointMigration = new SharepointMigration();
            sharepointMigration.Show();
            this.Hide();
            }

        private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OneDriveMigration oneDriveMigration = new OneDriveMigration();
            oneDriveMigration.Show();
            this.Hide();            
        }


        private void HomePage_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you have some *warnings* when you use the `async` keyword but the method doesn't `await` anything? Simply adding `async` to a method doesn't make its operations asynchronous. `SharepointMigration` and `OneDriveMigration` should make use of asynchronous methods, if possible, to do whatever they're supposed to do. Or start synchronous operations after the UI is already visible (to give some feedback on what's happening).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend performing navigation in the manner that you have - hiding parent forms etc.

Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60974350/how-to-open-a-form-from-the-main-one-then-i-come-back-to-the-main-one-and-then/60974748#60974748) it has an example of using a static class to perform the navigation and keep track of the navigation stack.